# SonarQube for Java: Make sure that command line arguments are used safely here

Tags: java, sonarqube

SonarQube for Java complains: "Make sure that command line arguments are used safely here" on the following code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.print(returnSum(args));
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("main: Input argument should be a number");
        }
    }

    public static int returnSum(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;

        if (args.length > 0) {
            try {
                for (String arg : args)
                    sum += Integer.parseInt(arg);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.out.println("returnSum: Input argument should be a number");
                throw nfe;
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

What else am I missing in order to satisfy SonarQube's requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a case of [sonarqube being overly zealous](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4823). It doesn't want you to pass the command line arguments array to another method as-is. Instead it thinks you should sanitize them in the `main` method.

One way to do that is doing to the string to integer conversion in the main method, and then it's "safe" to use the resulting array of numbers:

```
            int[] numbers = new int[args.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            }

            System.out.print(returnSum(numbers));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt help, Joni! Your advice did not help to remove the SonarQube's warning, unfortunately :( Also, I extracted `returnSum` method on purpose for the correct unit testing - so such approach was implemented on purpose.